# Create subset union type, based on condition. TypeScript

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have following `Widget` type:

```
enum WidgetType {
  Page = "Page",
  Tab = "Tab",
  Value = "Value",
  Chart = "Chart"
}
type PageWidget = {
  type: WidgetType.Page;
  children: Widget[];
};
type TabWidget = {
  type: WidgetType.Tab;
  children: Widget[];
};
type ValueWidget = {
  type: WidgetType.Value;
};
type ChartWidget = {
  type: WidgetType.Chart;
};
type Widget = PageWidget | TabWidget | ValueWidget | ChartWidget;
```

Based on that I want to create new type call `WidgetWithChildren` and it has to be an union of widgets which has `children` property (in this case is union of `PageWidget` and `TabWidget`), but I want to make it dynamical, so when there is a new type of Widget with children it will be automatically in `WidgetWithChildren`.

I want something like:

```
type WidgetWithChildren = Pick<Widget, "take widgets children">;
```

Is it possible in TypeScript? How can I do this?

Comment: use Extract<Union, 'oneOfYourTyped'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think in terms of depending only on what you need, you should be able to satisfy your need using an interface.

```
interface HierarchicalWidget {
    children: Widget[];
}

// Example usage
function needsChildren(widget: HierarchicalWidget) {
    for (const child of widget.children) {
        console.log(child.type);
    }
}
```

Any object that has `children` of type `Widget[]` can satisfy this interface, whether or not it explicitly implements it. This allows your code to depend on the concept of a `HierarchicalWidget` without having to know about the concrete implementations, such as `PageWidget` or `TabWidget`.